# Amazon Lex send the fulfilled slots via email

Tags: amazon-lex

I have created an Amazon Lex bot. The user has to fulfill some slots. Now I want to send the response (all fulfilled slots) via email to a specific address. Is this possible with Amazon Lex bot or do I have to create a Lambda function?

Thank you for your hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Lambda function or some other webhook where you will collect all the slots then trigger an email through your code or using some service like [AWS SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/).